# Worst Case number of rotations for BST to AVL algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have a basic algorithm below and I know that the worst case input BST is one that has degenerated to a linked list from inserts to only one side.

How would I compute the worst case complexity in terms of number of rotations for this BST to AVL conversion algorithm?

```
IF tree is right heavy
{
  IF tree's right subtree is left heavy
  {
     Perform Double Left rotation 
  }
  ELSE
  {
     Perform Single Left rotation
  }
}
ELSE IF tree is left heavy
{
  IF tree's left subtree is right heavy
  {
     Perform Double Right rotation
  }
  ELSE
  {
     Perform Single Right rotation
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If single and double rotations take constant time `O(1)` then for your worst-case input on size `n` it is going to perform single (or double depending on if your input  linked list is left-sided or right-sided) on all nodes. So it would be:

```
O(1) + O(1) + ... + O(1) # n times for worst case
```

That makes your algorithm `O(n)` for worst case.